# In a JPA named query in orm.xml, how do I pass an object as param and use its properties in JPQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using Spring data JPA. Specifically, the `JpaRepository` which contains `findByXXX` queries.

The scenario is that I have a query with a lot of parameters. It's ugly and impractical to put them all in a function. Just like

```
findByALotOfParams(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9);
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
class P {
    String p1;
    String p2;
    ...
    String p9;
}
findByALotOfParams(P p);
// and I can access the properties like :p.p1
```

In hibernate without Spring data jpa, there is something like

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
stock.setStockCode("7277");
String hql = "from Stock s where s.stockCode = :stockCode";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
    .setProperties(stock)
    .list();
```

And with [SpEL support](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) I can achieve this by something like

```
@Query("select s from Stock s where s.stockCode = :#{#param.stockCode}")
Iterable<Stock> findByStockCode(@Param("param") Stock stock);
```

However, the problem is, when I use a named query in orm.xml like

```
<named-query name="Stock.findByStockCode">
    <query>
        select s from Stock s where s.stockCode = :#{#param.stockCode}
    </query>
</named-query>
```

This doesn't work and gives the following error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '#'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's because JPA doesn't support Spring's SpEL syntax.  Have you tried the HQL equivalent to see if that works?