# Spring Boot - more cleaner or elegant way to pass multiple parameters to stored procedure spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, java-stored-procedures

how pass multiple parameters as DTO or Entity class in arguments method of Repository interface Spring Data

i have one procedure that receive multiple parameters of type IN and i have issue with my code in SonarQube
[Methods should not have too many parameters](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-107)

My Entity:

```java
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "MySPName", procedureName = "MySPName", parameters = {
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter1", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter2", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter3", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter4", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter5", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter6", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter7", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter8", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter9", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter10", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter11", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter12", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "parameter13", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "resultCode", type = Integer.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "resultMessage", type = String.class),
  @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "name", type = String.class)
})
public class MyEntitySP implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "resultCode")
  private Integer resultCode;

  @Column(name = "resultMessage")
  private String resultMessage;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
}
```

My Repository:

```java
public class MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntitySP, Integer> {
  @Procedure("MySPName")
  MyEntitySP callSP(@Param("parameter1") String parameter1, @Param("parameter2") String parameter2, @Param("parameter3") String parameter3, @Param("parameter4") String parameter4, @Param("parameter5") String parameter5, @Param("parameter6") String parameter6, @Param("parameter7") String parameter7, @Param("parameter8") String parameter8, @Param("parameter9") String parameter9, @Param("parameter10") String parameter10, @Param("parameter11") String parameter11, @Param("parameter12") String parameter12, @Param("parameter13") String parameter13) 
}
```

**I like anything as maybe Class Parameters:**

```java
public class MyParameters {
  @Param("parameter1")
  private String parameter1;

  @Param("parameter2")
  private String parameter2;

  @Param("parameter3")
  private String parameter3;

  @Param("parameter4")
  private String parameter4;

  @Param("parameter5")
  private String parameter5;
 
  @Param("parameter6")
  private String parameter6;

  @Param("parameter7")
  private String parameter7;

  @Param("parameter8")
  private String parameter8;

  @Param("parameter9")
  private String parameter9;

  @Param("parameter10")
  private String parameter10;

  @Param("parameter11")
  private String parameter11;

  @Param("parameter12")
  private String parameter12;

  @Param("parameter13)
  private String parameter13;
}
```

**and maybe Repository:**

```java
public class MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntitySP, Integer> {
  @Procedure("MySPName")
  MyEntitySP callSP(MyParameters parameters) 
}
```

**is it possible? - please help me***

Comment: You should try https://www.jooq.org/

Comment: thanks i see it good but I would like to in Spring Data and Repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to call a stored procedure using the `@Query` annotation to execute a native query (see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures).

By following that approach and using SPEL (see: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) then I think you could have something like:

```
public class MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntitySP, Integer> {
  @Query("MY_PROCEDURE(:#{#parameters.parameter1}, 
                       :#{#parameters.parameter2}, 
                       ....", nativeQuery = true)
  MyEntitySP callSP(MyParameters parameters) 
}
```

I do not see any easy solution when using `@Procedure` but, being Spring, there may be some custom parameter resolver you can apply

Comment: thanks currently I have decided to solve as you show it with the SPEL but SPEL not work in orm.xml

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718475/in-a-jpa-named-query-in-orm-xml-how-do-i-pass-an-object-as-param-and-use-its-pr)

what do you mean with "custom parameter resolver"?